# Modification and Access time of a file?

Tags: files, timestamps

Is it possible to change the file modification time without changing the file acess time?

Answer (score 4):

I found a way.  I used GNU stat (`stat (GNU coreutils) 8.19`) to look at "Access", "Modify" and "Change" timestamps of a file.

I could update the "Change" time by doing a `chmod u+x` on the file.  "Modify" and "Access" timestamps remained the same.

I could update "Access" file by doing a `cat` on it. "Modify" and "Change" timestamps remained the same.

I wrote a small C program that just does an `open(filename, O_WRONLY);`, writes a single byte to the file descriptor, and then a `close(filedes);` on the resulting file descriptor.  `stat` showed no change on the subject file's "Access" timestamp, but "Modify" and "Change" timestamps got updated.

This was all under Linux 3.5.4, a fairly recently update Arch Linux laptop, on an Ext4 filesystem.

The small C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
        int fd = open(av[1], O_WRONLY);
        if (fd >= 0)
        {
                char buf[12];
                write(fd, buf, 1);
                if (close(fd) < 0)
                        fprintf(stderr, "Problem closing file: %s\n",
                                strerror(errno));
        } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Problem opening \"%s\": %s\n",
                        av[1], strerror(errno));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this corrupt the file, since you are writing undefined data to the beginning of it?

Comment: Yes.  But it was the simplest example I could find.

Answer (score 4):

The [`utime`/`utimes` syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utime.2.html) lets you set the access and modification time arbitrarily. So you can `stat` the file, then use `utime` to change only one of them. From [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utime.2.html):

> **NAME**
>
> > utime, utimes - change file last access and modification times
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <sys/types.h>
>    #include <utime.h>
>
>    int utime(const char *filename, const struct utimbuf *times);
>
>    #include <sys/time.h>
>
>    int utimes(const char *filename, const struct timeval times[2]);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> > The  utime()  system  call changes the access and modification times of
> >     the inode specified by filename to the actime  and  modtime  fields  of
> >     times respectively.
> >
> > If  times  is  NULL, then the access and modification times of the file
> >     are set to the current time.
> >
> > Changing timestamps is permitted when: either the process has appropri‐
> >     ate  privileges,  or  the  effective  user ID equals the user ID of the
> >     file, or times is NULL and the process has  write  permission  for  the
> >     file.
> >
> > [ … ]

Answer (score 2):

Remount the FS with `noatime` attribute, change the file, and remount it back.

Answer (score 2):

Include the `-m` argument to `touch`. By default, the `touch` command modifies both the access time and the modification time; if you pass either `-a` or `-m` then only the specified time is modified.